# Where is reboot and shutdown power menu functionality in Hyperdrive custom ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, power-options

I just upgraded to Hyperdrive custom ROM RLS12 and now the long press power button is reassigned to control mute/vibrate/sound.

Where do I locate the normal power menu functionality that used to be on the power button held down to choose reboot, shutdown, etc.?

Comment: Please comment on the downvote so that I can improve future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the Hyperdrive ROM page for Note 3 at [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2301724), power menu toggle can be adjusted by the following steps.

1. Open the application `Hyperdrive Tweaks` included in the ROM.
2. In the app goto `General Mods > Extended Power Menu`
3. Select the options you want for power menu toggles viz (Shut Down /
   Restart / Recovery etc).

However, I cannot find out where to disable the Volume settings control from the power button, my assumption would be under Audio Mods of Hyperdrive Tweaks.

Reading further down in the thread, few have mentioned that enabling the power toggle in the Hyperdrive Tweaks app should override the current volume control toggle behaviour by power button (long press).